# Number triangle

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, linear-algebra, finite-fields, gm.general-mathematics

This question arose just out of curiosity. Note the triangle of 0-1's below, whose construction is as follows. Choose any number, say 53 as done here. The first line of the triangle is the binary representation (without any extra zeros padded). The next row of triangle is obtained by XOR-ing (adding modul0 2) two consecutive digits of above row, and so on till completion. 
$$
1~~1~~0~~1~~0~~1\\
0~~1~~1~~1~~1\\
1~~0~~0~~0\\
1~~0~~0\\
1~~0\\
1
$$
Now read off the numbers at the boundary of the triangle, clockwise. In the above example, that would be $1~1~0~1~0~1$, $1~1~0~0~0~1$ and $1~1~1~1~0~1$. That would be the triplet $(53, 49, 61)$. Note that if one had started with binary representation of 49 or 61 as the first row, the resulting triplet will be the same set of three numbers. In some sense, this is well-defined triplet.

Now, consider the number 13. We get the triangle:
$$
1~~1~~0~~1\\
0~~1~~1\\
1~~0\\
1
$$
Reading off numbers clockwise gives $(13,13,13)$, which is somewhat interesting. The same happens for numbers like 11, 39, 57 and so on. I wrote a code on python to get this sequence of special numbers till 500000. The graph below (which looks piecewise linear) depicts the number of integers less than a given integer which have this special property.[image]

Here are a few more observations/questions:

1. Pasted the first ten numbers of this sequence (11, 13, 39, 57, 83, 91, 101, 109, 151, 233, 543, 599) into OEIS, and it did not result in anything. Is there any literature on this?
2. The sequence can be seen as a set of solutions to a linear system of equations in $F_2$, as XOR operation is equivalent to addition in $F_2$. Could that be used to prove that this sequence is (in)finite?
3. The same can be done for a representation in any base. How would that compare to the binary one?
4. How does one explain the graph?
5. Is the sequence of any serious research interest, in general?

Comment: Writing at the beginning that xoring= adding mod 2 would save time (I googled to find the definition).

Comment: Have you counted, among those numbers, the palindromic ones? (i.e., those for which the resulting triangle has a symmetry group of order 6)

Comment: @YCor, thanks for the comments. Have edited XOR-ing accordingly. Have not checked for palindromes yet. Will do that too and post result in the next comment.

Comment: @YCor, there are no palindromes (in binary representation) till 500000.

Comment: Note that reversing the binary expansion induces an involution on the your set of numbers, whose fixed points are the palindromes, exchanging 11—13, 39—57, 83—101, 91—109, etc. Maybe you can test palindromes until much further than 500000, since a palindrome is governed by twice less digits.

Comment: @YCor, thanks for that nice observation. Will try that.

Comment: OK, thinking more: say you're considering triangles with $n$ vertices on each large edge. You're first counting those 0-1 (mod 2) valued triangles with the property that the sum is zero on each triangle. The number of solutions of this is then a power of 2. This remains true if you add any symmetry condition, and also if you impose an affine condition, such as the condition that extreme vertices are marked with $1$.

Comment: For every $n$ the number of solutions with $n$ binary digits is thus a power of 2, so it would make more sense to compute, instead of the number of solutions $\le m$, the number $2^{u_n}$ of solutions in $[2^n,2^{n+1}[$, which should be computable in terms of ranks of some matrices. Maybe these matrices have a homological interpretation, I'm not sure.

Comment: @YCor, I am not sure if I completely understand your comment relating to constructing 0-1 triangles with n-vertices, apart from basic similarity to the original question. Guess what you're suggesting is to view the graph in log-scale?

Comment: To start with, compute for $n<19$  the number of solutions $k$ such that $2^n\le k<2^m$ (i.e., with exactly $n+1$ binary digits). it should be a power of 2, do you confirm?

Comment: BTW I checked there's no palindrome, by arguing around the center of the triangle. Still, if you allow numbers starting with zero, you have a few: the 0 triangle, and only one other for each $n=3m+1$: the triangle (drawn for $n=7$) $$\begin{matrix}0&&1&&1&&0&&1&&1&&0\\&1&&0&&1&&1&&0&&1&\\&&1&&1&&0&&1&&1&&\\&&&0&&1&&1&&0&&&\\&&&&1&&0&&1&&&&\\&&&&&1&&1&&&&&\\&&&&&&0&&&&&&\end{matrix}$$.

Comment: @YCor, can you elaborate your logic about non-existence of palindromes?

Comment: And, also the logic for the number of solution being power of 2. I am certainly missing some logic here.

Comment: It's not logic, it's interpreting the problem as solving a system of linear equations over $F_2$. Hence basic linear algebra.

Comment: My reasoning was not correct in excluding palindromes (by mistake I assumed that reversed little triangles also sum to zero). Reasoning from the center remains anyway probably the right way to get classification. Probably the resulting dimensions are related to the homology mod-2 of the space consisting of this triangulation, with only tiling triangles with vertex on the bottom being filled. This would justify that the number $2^{u_n}$ of solutions of your problem in $[2^n,2^{n+1}[$ should have $u_n$ quadratic in $n$ (with discussion on $n$ mod 3), experiments can lead to the right conjecture.

Comment: @YCor, thanks for the clarification. I'll think about the reasoning surrounding palindromes. One complete classification of solutions between two powers of 2 is the set of solutions to a set of linear equations, which I've mentioned in the question. Number of solutions also being a power of two, is simple. My bad. :)

Comment: My expectation $u_n$ quadratic isn't correct, it's simpler. It seems $u_{n+3}=u_n+3$ for the counting without symmetry. Precisely here $u_n$ is the number of ways to assign to each vertex of a triangulation as in your picture, with $n$ vertices on the top (hence $n(n+1)/2$ vertices), a boolean number so that every upside down small triangle sums to 0. If $v_n$ counts those with rotational symmetry, we get $v_{n+3}=v_n+1$; precisely in this case, the palindromic ones *are* those with 0 on the corners, and you count the non-palindromic ones. Counting palindromic should involve discussion mod 2.

Comment: PS what I asserted in the previous comment implies in particular that the sum (mod 2) of any two solutions is a palindrome. That is, the solutions (with rotational symmetry and 1 on corners) form an affine space whose linear part is the set of palindrome solutions (necessarily with 0 on extremities). For instance,  $[1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1]+[1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1]=[0,0,0,1,0,0,0]$.

Comment: When you work mod 2, addition is the same as subtraction. So the second row gives the first differences of the first row, the third row gives the second differences, and so on. Then you can recover the top row from the left side as a sum of binomial coefficients. E.g., for top row 1101, the left side is 1011, so $1+{n\choose2}+{n\choose3}$ gives $1,1,0,1$, respectively, for $n=0,1,2,3$, respectively (working mod 2). So you can write down what a "special" number is, in terms of binomial coefficients.

Comment: A cool question.  You should ask how many triangles there are of each size having the properties you care about.  This number will be a power of two since these triangles are a vector spaced over $F_2$.

Comment: The nonexistence of palindromic solutions is trivial. Let $a$ be the entry immediately to the right of the $1$ in the upper left corner, let $b$ be the entry immediately below that $1$ (so, the first entry in the 2nd row). For a palindrome, $a=b$. But by construction of the triangle, $1+a=b$. Contradiction.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, thanks for that nice proof, and the earlier observation.

Comment: It seems that solutions do not exist only for length of the form $2^k+1$.

Comment: What I checked the other day is that the number of solutions (rotation invariant and allowing 0 on corners) is $2^{u_n}$ with $u_n=n+v_n$, and $v_n$ 3-periodic with $v_0=v_1=1$ and $v_2=-2$. It follows that the number of solutions with $1$ on the corner is either $0$, or $2^{u_n-1}$, say $t_n2^{u_n-1}$ with $t_n\in\{0,1\}$. I expected  $t_n$ to depend on $n$ modulo $2$, but actually it seems to rather depend on $n-1$ being a $2$-power. So the counting problem is completely settled. It's easy to describe an algorithm to enumerate the solutions (allowing 0 on corners) passing from $n-3$ to $n$.

Comment: @YCor, your comments look very interesting, but are tough to read as written.  Would you be willing to promote them to an answer, so that they can be read full size and all at once?

Comment: @LSpice OK I finally did it (time-consuming, this is why I was hesitating at writing down... what I said about palindromes (namely that all rotational-invariant solutions with 0 on corners )are palindromes seems suspicious by the way.

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev, thanks for that interesting observation.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, guess your logic regarding non-existence of palindromes holds good for any base-representation.

Comment: Michael De Vlieger, an OEIS contributor, made [a visually stunning image that contains hundreds of these triangles](http://www.vincico.com/seq/a334556-3.png) (with top row encoded by $1, 11, 13, 39, 57, 83, \dots$).

Comment: @PeterKagey, wow! Didn't expect that. And, thanks to Michael De Vlieger.

Answer (score 5):

$\def\Ker{\operatorname{Ker}}$Let me try to rewrite my answer --- at least, for clarity reasons. Thanks to Pat Devlin and YCor for stimulation.

First, several definitions. A $k$-triangle is a triangle constructed in the described way. We work over $\mathbb F_2$; the $k$-dimensional coordinate space is denoted by $V_k$ (so, any side of a $k$-triangle is a vector in this space). There is a linear operator $\varphi_k\colon V_k\to V_k$ mapping the top vector of a $k$-triangle into its right vector. We have $\varphi_k^3=1$, so $V_k=U_k\oplus W_k$, where $U_k=\Ker(\varphi+1)$ and $W_k=\Ker(\varphi^2+\varphi+1)$ (recall that $1=-1$). Denote $u_k=\dim U_k$ and $w_k=\dim W_k$ (*one can see that $w_k$ is always even*). For every $v\in V_k$, its $U_k$- and $W_k$-part are $x_u=(\varphi_k^2+\varphi_k+1)x\in U_k$ and $x_w=(\varphi_k^2+\varphi)x\in W_k$ (recall that $x=x_u+x_w$).

We say that vectors in $U_k$ are *stable*. Vectors starting with $1$ are *proper*. So, we are interested in the number of proper stable vectors, and it is either $2^{u_k-1}$ or $0$, depeding on whether $U_k$ contains a proper vector or not.

**Observation 1.** Each vector in $U_k$ has equal first and last coordinates. So, for $k\geq 2$ the space $W_k$ contains a vector with distinct first and last coordinates. The triangles of such vectors have all three sides in $W_k$ and have two ones at the corners. Hence, there are vectors in $W_k$ starting with $1$ and endind with $0$, starting with $0$ and ending with $1$, and also starting and ending with $1$.

Introduce also the following mixing operator. If $a,b\in V_k$, then $\mu_{2k}(a,b)=(a_1,b_1,a_2,b_2,\dots,a_k,b_k)\in V_{2k}$. If $a\in V_{k+1},b\in V_k$, then $\mu_{2k+1}(a,b)=(a_1,b_1,\dots,a_k,b_k,a_{k+1})\in V_{2k+1}$. For $c\in V_n$, denote by $o(c)\in V_{\lceil n/2\rceil}$ and $e(c)\in V_{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}$ the unique vectors such that $\mu_n(o(),e(c))=c$.

The indices will be omitted when they are clear.

Finally, for a vector $c\in V_{k+1}$ we denote by $c\rangle, \langle c\in V_k$ the vector $c$ without the last coordinate and without the first coordinate, respectively. By $\overleftarrow c$ we denote the left cyclic shift of $c$, i.e., $(c_2,c_3,\dots,c_1)$.

**Observation 2.** The sum of the three digits in the vertices of a $3$-triangle is zero. By induction, the same holds for any $(2^k+1)$-triangle.

**Corollary 1.** There are no proper stabe vectors in $U_{2^k+1}$.

**Corollary 2.** Ay $k$-triangle falls into four sparse triangles (of sizes $\lceil k/2\rceil$, $\lfloor k/2\rfloor$,  $\lfloor k/2\rfloor$, and $\lceil k/2\rceil-1$).

**Corollary 3. (a)** Let $a,b\in V_k$, and let $\varphi_{2k}(\mu(a,b))=\mu(c,d)$. Then $c=\varphi_k(b)$ and $d=\varphi_k(a)+c=\varphi_k(a+b)$. The first claim is clear; the second follows from the observation that a sparse $k$-triangle with $d$ on the right has $a+b$ on the top.

**(b)** Let $a\in V_{k+1}$, $b\in V_k$, and let $\varphi_{2k+1}(\mu(a,b))=\mu(c,d)$. Then $c=\varphi_{k+1}(a)$ and $d=\varphi_k(b+\langle a)=\varphi_k(b)+c\rangle$.

Hugh. Now come to the problem itself.

Assume first that **$n=2k$ is even**. Then $c=\mu(a,b)\in V_{2k}$ lies in $U_{2k}$ iff $a=\varphi_k(b)$ and $b=\varphi_k(a+b)$, so $b=\varphi_k^2(b)+\varphi_k(b)$, i.e., $b\in W_k$ (and hence $a\in W_k$ as well). Therefore, we have a one-to-one correspondence $W_k\to U_{2k}$ given by $a\mapsto \mu(a,\varphi^2(a))$, and proper vectors correspond to proper ones.

Therefore, 
$$
  u_{2k}=w_k=k-u_k,
$$ 
and the number of proper stable $2k$-vectors is $2^{w_k-1}$ by Observation 1.

Now comes a bit harder case when **$n=2k+1$ is odd**. A vector $c=\mu(a,b)\in V_{2k+1}$ is stable iff $\varphi(a)=a$ and $\varphi(b)=b+a\rangle$, which rewrites as $a\rangle=(\varphi+1)(b)=\varphi^2(b_w)$. Similarly, we get $\langle a(=\overleftarrow{a\rangle})=\varphi(b_w)$.

So, basicaly we need to search for (proper) $a\in U_{k+1}$ such that $a\rangle\in W_k$; each such will lead to $2^{w_k}$ (proper) stable vectors of the form $\mu(a,b)$, where $b_u=\varphi(a\rangle)$. In other words, we need to find the dimendsion of $W_k\cap (U_{k+1}\rangle)$ and check whether it contains proper vectors.

But in fact $U_{k+1}\rangle \subseteq W_k$. Indeed,  take the $(k+1)$-triangle with first row $a$ and remove that first row. We will get the $k$-triangle with top vector $\langle a+a\rangle$, right vector $\langle a$ and left vetor $a\rangle$ which sum up to $0$, as desired.

Hence we get 
$$
  u_{2k+1}=u_{k+1}+u_k.
$$

Now the small values yield the dimensions claimed by YCor, namely $u_k=a,a+1,a$ when, respectively, $k=3a,3a+1,3a+2$. Mpreover, each $U_{2k}$ contains a proper vector, and $U_{2k+1}$ does contains a one iff $U_{k+1}$ does. This yields that proper stable vectors exist for all $n$ except for those of the form $2^t+1$, and their number is exactly $2^{u_n-1}$ in all thoese cases. We are done.

Comment: There is an error in your reasoning for the even case.  For instance, $n=4$ and $n=6$ and $n=8$ all have the same number of solutions (all have 2 solutions if we require the top left entry to be 1).  $n=10$ has 8 solutions (if we require top left entry to be 1).

Comment: @PatDevlin: Thanks for pointing that out! I've made some corrections (and introduced one new idea); seems that it is corrected now. Does a new text agree with the numerical data?

Comment: Added some Addendum which makes the things more clear.

Comment: It seems that you haven't still reached the modulo 3 phenomenon. Namely, define $f(3n)=f(3n+2)=2^{n-1}$, $f(3n+1)=2^{n}$. Then the number of solutions, if nonzero, is equal to $f(n)$. (While $2f(n)$ is, for every $n\ge 0$, the number of solutions allowing $0$ on corners.)

Comment: I@YCor: Yes, in these terms I now know that $2f(k)\cdot 2f(2k)=2^k$ which seems to agree with this formula. An advantage is that I know that for any even $n$ there _are_ solutions with leading ones... Need to think more about an odd case.

Comment: This seems better, but your assertion (in both cases) that $b = a + c$ doesn’t look like it’s true to me.  I agree that in the case that $n$ is even, then the vector $b$ is completely determined by the vector $a$.  And in the odd case, $a$ must be a solution to the case $(n+1)/2$.  But this looks like it has good ideas that can be worked into a correct solution.

Comment: @Pat Perhaps, it is too sketchy; I will try to fill the details or to rewrite all this.

Comment: Ah!  I’m seeing it now!  If I finish sorting out the case of n odd, then I could either (i) edit your answer to include this (and perhaps to be a bit clearer in parts) or (ii) post a follow-up answer.  Whichever you’d prefer

Comment: @Pat: Wait till I finish editing it in a clearer manner, please. Perhaps I'll also sort it out -- still unsure.

Comment: Sounds good.  Also.  I now see that the dimension of U_k seems to be floor(k/3) when k is not 2 mod 3, and otherwise it seems to be floor(k/3) + 1.  In particular, it seems like  dim(U_k) = dim(U_{k+3}) - 1

Comment: Actually my argument doesn't involve parity of $n$, and just passes from each solution (allowing 0 on corners) for $n-3$ to two solutions for $n$. It just doesn't say, for given $n$, whether all solutions have 0 on corners, or if half of them have 1 on corners).

Comment: Done! Could I ask some of you to cjeck?

Comment: Oh, great!  Nice work on the odd case.  That’s a satisfying solution.  :-)

Comment: @YCor, after this all has been done --- isn't your solution beter in a sense that it could provide more _uniformity_? The OP's graphs look really piecewise-linear --- is it true that your construction confirms that? Does it preserve some order of the proper vectors, or it rather smashes them all around?

Comment: My solution easily describes the dimension (when nonzero) $u_n$ of the solutions of size $n$; nevertheless it does not say how the $2^{u_n}$ numbers thus defined by binary expansion distribute in $[2^{n-1},2^n]$. The picture might suggest it tends to a uniform distribution (this ought to be confirmed, or not, by more precise computations). I haven't thought about it so far.

Comment: @IlyaBogdanov, thanks for some brilliant observations. Taking some cues from your thoughts, I guess one can construct infinitely many special numbers from one special number. The idea is: if $(a_1,a_2, \cdots. a_n)$ is a special number, then $(a_1,a_2, \cdots. a_n, a_2, \cdots. a_n )$ must also be special. This can be seen easily by pasting 4 triangles of $(a_1,a_2, \cdots. a_n)$, appropriately. I did check this on Python starting with (1,1,0,1). Let me know if there's an error in logic.

Comment: It does not seem so; one of your four triangles is turned upside-down, and such triangles ate governed by different rules. Check out doubling 111001

Comment: On the other hand,if a doubling works on a specific word, then you can add an arbitrary number of such runs, and it will work as well.

Comment: @IlyaBogdanov, I agree with your logic. I think I just gor lucky with 13, 109 and ignored that intricacy. Thanks for that!

Answer (score 0):

OK, let $V_n$ be the vertex set of the following tiling by triangle with $n$ vertices at each large edge. Let me call "standing triangle" a little tiling triangle with a single vertex on the bottom.

For an abelian group $A$, let $A^{V_n}$ be the group of all maps $V_n\to A$. Let $P_n^1(A)$ be its subgroup consisting of those maps summing to zero on each standing triangle. Let $P_n^3(A)$ be the subgroup of $P_n^1(A)$ consisting of those maps that are invariant under $2\pi/3$ rotation.

The perimeter of $V_n$ being the union of its boundary edges, its complement can be identified to $V_{n-3}$. For instance, this picture depicts $\emptyset=V_0\subset V_3\subset V_6$.

$$\begin{matrix} \circ && \circ && \circ && \circ && \circ && \circ\\
&\circ && \circ && \circ && \circ && \circ &\\
&&\circ && \circ && \circ && \circ &&\\
&&& \circ && \circ && \circ &&&\\
&&&& \circ && \circ &&&&\\
&&&&& \circ &&&&&
\end{matrix}$$

We proceed to describe $P^i_n(A)$ for each $n$ and $i=1,3$, by passing from $n$ to $n+3$. Hence we start with $n=0,1,2$.

- $n=0$: $V_0$ is empty, so clearly $P_0^1(A)=P_0^3(A)=\{0\}$.
- $n=1$: $V_1$ is a singleton, so clearly $P_0^1(A)=P_0^3(A)=A$.
- $n=2$: $V_2$ is a single standing triangle. Let $A_3=\{a\in A:3a=0\}$. Then $P_0^1(A)$ can be identified to triples of $A$ with sum zero, while $P_0^3(A)=A_3$.

To pass from $n-3$ to $n\ge 3$, we describe the restriction map $P_n^i(A)\to P_{n-3}^i(A)$. Start from $f$ defined on $V_{n-3}$. Then propose some values $a$, $b$, $c$ on the "right" of each extremal vertex:

$$\begin{matrix}
&\circ && a && \circ && \circ && \circ &\\
&&\circ && u && v && b &&\\
&&& \circ && w && \circ &&&\\
&&&& c && \circ &&&&\\
&&&&& \circ &&&&&
\end{matrix}$$

Then using the sum zero condition, this imposes by propagation values to the right on each edge:

$$\begin{matrix}
&x\quad && a && -a-u && a+u-v && y &\\
&& c-u+w && u  && v && b\quad &&\\
&&& -c-w && w && -b-v &&&\\
&&&& c && b+v-w &&&&\\
&&&&& z &&&&&
\end{matrix}$$
$$\text{with}\qquad (x,y,z)=(-a-b-u+v,\;-b-c-v+w,\;-a-c+u-w)$$
(sorry the for the poor alignment of matrix mode)

No further condition is to be fulfilled. This constructs a splitting of the restriction map $P_n^1(A)\to P_{n-3}^1(A)$, which in particular is surjective, and has its kernel isomorphic to $A^3$ (corresponding to $(a,b,c)$). In addition, this is compatible with the rotational symmetry, in which case we have to impose $a=b=c$. Thus, $P_n^1(A)$ is isomorphic to $P_{n-3}(A)\oplus A^3$ and $P_n^3(A)$ is isomorphic to $P_{n-3}(A)\oplus A$ (as abelian groups).

This proves that, for every $n\ge 0$

- $P^1_{3n}(A)$ is isomorphic to $A^{3n}$ and $P^3_{3n}(A)$ is isomorphic to $A^n$;
- $P^1_{3n+1}(A)$ is isomorphic to $A^{3n+1}$ and $P^3_{3n+1}(A)$ is isomorphic to $A^{n+1}$
- $P^1_{3n+2}(A)$ is isomorphic to $A^{3n+2}$ and $P^3_{3n+2}(A)$ is isomorphic to $A_3\oplus A^n$ (hence to $A^n$ if $A$ has no element of order 3).

The method also described an efficient algorithm to generate bases of these, and hence the boundary numbers which are the original objects of study (when $A=\mathbf{F}_2$).

Let us now assume that $A=K$ is a field. The problem asks about the subset $P^3_n(K)_1$, defined with the condition that the extremal vertices are labeled by $1$. This is either empty or an affine hyperplane. If nonempty, this fully describes its dimension as affine subspace (namely $3n\mapsto n-1$, $3n+1\mapsto n$, $3n+2\mapsto n-1$ [or $n$ iff $K$ has characteristic 3].

Note that all this does not say when precisely $P^3_n(K)_1$ is non-empty. When $K$ has characteristic 2 (which boils down to $\mathbf{F}_2$) it was conjectured in the comments that it's empty iff $n=0$ or $n-1$ is a power of $2$.

The description of palindromic solutions $P^6_n(A)$ (i.e., invariant under rotation and reflection) is not obvious and seems also sensitive to the binary expansion of $n$ in some way. However, in characteristic 2 it is clearly equal to $P^6_n(K)_0$, i.e. each extremal vertex is labeled zero, since it forms a standing triangle with two vertices labeled with the same number. That is, $P^6_n(K)_1$ is empty.

---

To be more explicit: the above produces, for $n\ge 3$, a way to pass from
$P^3_{n-3}(A)$ to $P^3_n(A)$ explicit in terms of the boundary word. Let me specify to $A=\mathbf{F}_2$ which is the OP's framework: if we have the boundary word $(u_1,\dots,u_{n-3})$, then it has two "successors" of size $n$:
$$\begin{matrix}(v_{n-3},&0,& u_1&,&u_1+u_2
&,\dots,&
&v_{n-3}&,&v_{n-3})\\
(v_{n-3},&1,&1+u_1&,&1+u_1+u_2
&,\dots,&
&1+v_{n-3}&,&v_{n-3})
\end{matrix}$$
In particular, a solution with $1$ on the corners exists in size $n$ if and only if a solution with nonzero sum (that is, $v_{n-3}\neq 0$) —but possibly 0 on the corners— exists in size $n-3$.